# How can I stop the auto login console and getty in Raspbian 8 (Jessie)?

Tags: raspbian, boot

How can I stop auto serial port auto login console and getty in the Raspbian 8 (Jessie) OS, and why is `/etc/inittab/` empty?

Where can I get this (#Spawn a getty on Raspberry Pi serial line
T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100 ) in Raspbian 8 (Jessie)?

Comment: Jessie uses `systemd`. If you want to ask Linux questions use http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 11):

inittab was a part of sysvinit, which has been replaced with systemd.. Serial getty is now a service like any other. So in order to stop this service, simply write in terminal;

```
sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
```

Comment: If you don't want  it to start again at boot, you will also need `systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service`.

Answer (score 5):

For Raspbian try

```
sudo raspi-config
```

It should have an option to disable serial boot messages and getty under Advanced -> Serial.

You may need to reboot for that to take affect.

Alternatively disable the service if running with systemd.

```
sudo sysctl -p
sudo systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
```

Comment: @joan what does the `sudo sysctl -p` do and/or why is it used?

Comment: @DiederikdeHaas I can tell you what man says but that does not help.  It is just something I have seen done before the systemctl command and frankly I have no idea if it is needed or not.

Comment: I've seen the manpage (and `sysctl --help`) but it didn't tell me much. Tried it myself and didn't see anything visible happen and I had never seen the use of it before disabling a service with systemd.

Comment: You can switch back to the `sysvinit` package in Jessie (it was the default in all previous Raspian & Debian distributions) if you really want to - and once you have rebooted so that `init` is your PID 1 you can then uninstall `systemd` - you may need to add/remove other dependencies. I haven't been much impressed by systemd in some areas (documentation; use in non-"standard" system settings) and that is why I try to avoid it like the plague...

Comment: I also believe that the systemctl disable command will stop the getty from restarting after rebooting, but if we want to stop it while it is already running we might need:

`sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service`

Comment: sysctl and systemctl are different things, sysctl is not part of systemd. You do not need ``sysctl -p``

Comment: @DiederikdeHaas The manpage explains it very clearly: `sysctl -p` loads the default values from `/etc/sysctl.conf`. If you had changed some values manually before, this command restores the default again. I don't think this is needed.

Comment: For me disabling the serial console login through raspi-config also disabled /dev/ttyAMA0. I had to enable /dev/ttyAMA0 again  by editing /boot/config.txt and setting enable_uart=1.